# Insert multiple values of checkbox in db in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm new to cakephp and get in trouble .I'm trying to insert values of checkbox in db after clicking on save button i'm getting an error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
```

My Query:

```
INSERT INTO `cake_demo`.`users` (`name`, `username`, `password`, `city`, `hobbies`) 
VALUES ('', '', '', '', Array)
```

Comment: paste the code with $model->save()

Comment: What should be saved in the `hobbies` column? A comma delimited list? _Shouldn't that column be replaced with another table for proper normalized design (user hasmany hobbies and hobby hasmany users -> user hasAndBelongsToMany hobbies?_

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert an array in one field from your database please serialize it

```
serialize($array);
```

If you fetch it from your database you can unserialize it:

```
unserialize($serializedStr);
```

Another option is to save it as JSON string

```
json_encode($arr);
```

To get array:

```
json_decode($jsonStr, true);
```